# Small question about ODE

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

i have this question :

> Given  three parameters $L,a$ et $\alpha$, we consider the
>   differential equation : $$(E)\qquad x''+\alpha x' +a x + \sin x =L, \ 
> > t\geq0$$
>
> **1)** Show that the maximal solutions of $(E)$ are defined on all $\mathbb {R}$.
>
> **2)** Assume that $a>0$ et $\alpha \geq 0$.
>
> **a)** Establish the existence of a positive constant $C$ such that :
>
> $\displaystyle \frac{a}{4}x^2+\frac{y^2}{2}\leq C+1+\frac{L^2}{a^2}$
>    (You can use the functional $V(x,y)=\frac12 y^2+\frac{a}{2}x^2-L
>  x-\cos x)$

I suppose that $y(t)=x'(t)$ , i have $\frac{dV}{dt}=-\alpha y^2$ so $V$ is decreasing but i don't know how to prove the existence of a positive $C$ such that :$\displaystyle \frac{a}{4}x^2+\frac{y^2}{2}\leq C+1+\frac{L^2}{a^2}$

I just find that : $\displaystyle\frac{y^2}{2}+\frac{a}{4}x^2 \leq V(x_0;y_0) + 1 + Lx-\frac{a}{4}x^2$

but how to find $\displaystyle\frac{L^2}{a^2}$ ??????????

Please help me

Thank you .

Comment: How are $x,y,t$ related to each other? Are $a,\alpha,L$ constants?

Comment: All i have is that $L,a,\alpha$ are parameters and $t$ is the time , $x(t)$ is the solution of $E$ and $y(t)=x'(t)$

Comment: please ave you any idea about this question ? pleaseeeee @robjohn

Comment: Are you sure it is $\frac{L^2}{a^2}$? I get $\frac{L^2}{a}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiply by $x'$ and integrate to get
$$
\frac12x'^2+\alpha\int x'^2\,\mathrm{d}t+\frac12ax^2-\cos(x)=Lx+C\tag{1}
$$
Since $\alpha\ge0$ and $\cos(x)\le1$, $(1)$ implies
$$
\frac12x'^2+\frac12ax^2\le C+1+Lx\tag{2}
$$
Subtracting $\frac14ax^2$ from both sides
$$
\frac12x'^2+\frac14ax^2\le C+1+Lx-\frac14ax^2\tag{3}
$$
maximum of $Lx-\frac14ax^2$ is $\frac{L^2}{a}$ at $x=\frac{2L}{a}$. Therefore, I get
$$
\frac12x'^2+\frac14ax^2\le C+1+\frac{L^2}{a}\tag{4}
$$

Comment: we multiply (E) by x'.,and when we have use V thank you  ?

Comment: @Vrouvrou: yes. Note that $$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\frac12x'^2=x'x''$$ and that $$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\frac12x^2=xx'$$ and that $$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}Lx=Lx'$$ $V(x,y)$ is a hint. Differentiate it with respect to $t$ and see.

Comment: $dV/dt= x'(x''+ax-L+\sin x )$ , $\alpha x'$ don't appear !

Comment: @Vrouvrou: but as that doesn't appear in the final formula, all they are expecting is that $\int\alpha x'^2\,\mathrm{d}t$ is positive.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/users/13854/robjohn: please how to be sure that C is positive ? thank you

Comment: @Vrouvrou: In $(1)$, $C=\frac12x'^2(0)-1$. Furthermore, if the inequality is true for a negative $C$, it is certainly true for $C=1$.

Comment: i don't understand ! what happen if C=1??

Comment: @Vrouvrou: you asked to show that $C\gt0$. $C$ can be any number not less than $\frac12x'^2(0)-1$.