# Bounded solutions of ODE

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I have this ODE  $(E)... x''+\alpha x'+ax+\sin x =L , t\geq 0$ 
we suppose that  $a>0$and $\alpha \geq 0$ , and that there existe un constant $C>0$ such that

$\frac{a}{4}x^2+\frac{y^2}{2}\leq C+1+\frac{L^2}{a}$

$y=x'$

how to prove that the solutions of $(E)$ are bounded when $t\rightarrow +\infty$ ?

Thank you .

Comment: This question is confusing as written. Are you sure you wrote it correctly? Regards

Comment: We don't need V i edited my question ,thank you

Comment: What is y here ?

Comment: @Vrouvrou: Is $L$ a function of $x$ or $t$ or a constant?

Comment: L is a constant and y=x'

Comment: Since $\frac{a}{4}x^2+\frac{1}{2}y^2\le C+1+\frac{L^2}{2}$, you can get $x^2\le M$ for some $M(a,L,C)>0$ which implies that $x(t)$ is bounded. What do you want to get?

Comment: That's all ? ok thank you ! please can you see here please :http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/442776/complicated-exercise-on-ode

Comment: @xpaul how to find the M, we have the $y$ !!!!!

Comment: @Vrouvrou, it is easy to get $M$. Note that $\max\{\frac{a}{4}x^2,\frac{1}{2}y^2\}\le\frac{a}{4}x^2+\frac{1}{2}y^2\le C+1+\frac{L^2}{2}$ and hence $\max\{x^2,y^2\}\le M$, where $M=\max\{\frac{4}{a}(C+1+\frac{L^2}{2}),2C+2+L^2\}$.